# Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle while building flutter application apk

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Recently I updated the Gradle version of my flutter application. I made the following changes

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.2.1
```

in gradle.properties

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22' and
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

in top level build.gradle.

But when I try to create an apk using flutter build apk command, I get the following error

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

     android {
         namespace 'com.example.namespace'
     }

     If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           10.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

But the namespace is already present in app/src/build.gradle. as shown below

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    
    namespace "com.example.educationadmin"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.educationadmin"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
         multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
     implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
}
```

and top level build file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: are you using the latest stable version of 'flutter_inappwebview'? according to the source code, they have this property: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/blob/master/flutter_inappwebview_android/android/build.gradle#L26-L27

Comment: This could be caused by one of the dependencies you are using. I can recommend to go over your pubspec.yaml file and see which dependency this might be originating from.

Comment: I am not using flutter_inappwebview directly in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following method.

The inappwebview module is not installed inside Android, but it is installed in the iOS folder. In the directory ios/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_inappwebview/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, and ios/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_inappwebview/android/build.gradle,

you can make it work by adding the package name from AndroidManifest.xml to the namespace in build.gradle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgk2E.jpg)